# Editing related objects in ModelFormSet

Tags: python, django

I have these Models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")

class Image(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
   Gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images')

class Tour(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Count=models.SmallIntegerField() 
   ActionUser=models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)
   Gallery = models.OneToOneField(Gallery,editable=False)
```

as U can see,I have a form for tour and a form for gallery and a formset for gallerie's Images,in edittour view I wanna edit a Tour with it's gallery and gallerie's images.this is code to edit a Tour with it's related objects:

```
def edittour(request,key,tour_id):
   ImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Gallery,Image, can_delete=False,extra=4)
   tourinstance=Tour.objects.get(pk=tour_id)
   if request.method == 'POST':
      gform=GalleryForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=tourinstance.Gallery)
      if gform.is_valid():
         gallery=gform.save(commit=False)
         formset=ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=tourinstance.Gallery)
         if formset.is_valid():
            gallery.save()
            formset.save()
         tform = TourForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=tourinstance)
         if tform.is_valid():
            tour=tform.save(commit=False)
            tour.ActionUserCode=User.objects.get(pk=1)
            tour.save()
            return render_to_response('airAgency/edittour.html', {'tform': tform,'gform':gform,'formset':formset})#'airAgency/edittour/%i/' % (tour.pk))
   else:
      pass
   tform = TourForm(instance=tourinstance)
   gform=GalleryForm(instance=tourinstance.Gallery)
   formset=ImageFormSet(instance=tourinstance.Gallery)
   return render_to_response('airAgency/edittour.html', {'tform': tform,'gform':gform,'formset':formset})
```

this works well when I edit Tour,but when I edit Image_set related to gallery it has this error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /airAgency/mastane/edittour/1/

"Key 'images-0-id' not found in <QueryDict: {u'Count': [u'15'], u'images-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'5'], u'images-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u''], u'HeadImage': [u''], u'Description': [u'-'], u'PriceUnitCode': [u'1'], u'images-3-Image': [u''], u'images-2-Image': [u''], u'Price': [u'15000000'], u'StatusTypeCode': [u'2'], u'images-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'1'], u'images-0-Image': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'e0a3aef084f11305a7610befda7cb27a'], u'images-4-Image': [u''], u'Name': [u'\\u0645\\u0627\\u0644\\u0632\\u06cc']}>"

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/airAgency/mastane/edittour/1/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

"Key 'images-0-id' not found in <QueryDict: {u'Count': [u'15'], u'images-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'5'], u'images-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u''], u'HeadImage': [u''], u'Description': [u'-'], u'PriceUnitCode': [u'1'], u'images-3-Image': [u''], u'images-2-Image': [u''], u'Price': [u'15000000'], u'StatusTypeCode': [u'2'], u'images-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'1'], u'images-0-Image': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'e0a3aef084f11305a7610befda7cb27a'], u'images-4-Image': [u''], u'Name': [u'\\u0645\\u0627\\u0644\\u0632\\u06cc']}>"

Exception Location:     C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 256
```

...

Comment: you are usually more likely to get good help if you reduce down your example to the minimum required to show your problem (e.g. removing all other code.) This has the added bonus of often making the bug obvious enough for you to spot yourself

Comment: ok!now I reduced down the code.please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are manually rendering the form in your template, and missing out the id field. Make sure you include `{{ form.id }}` for each form in the formset.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.id }}
        <ul>
            <li>{{ form.title }}</li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

See the docs on [using model formsets in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template) for more information.