# add an object along with it's related objects in the same form in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery") 

class Image(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
   Gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images',blank=True)

class Agency(models.Model):
   # some fields ...
   Gallery=models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
```

Now I want to, when adding an Agency, instead of showing just an stupid combobox for Gallery field, I have these things:

A file upload for `HeadImage` field in `Gallery` model and a set of file uploads 
for `Image` field in `Image` model. Some thing like adding an object(Agency) with it's related objects(Gallery related to Agency and Image related to gallery)in one form. How can I do this? I didn't find any solution after googling a lot, that sounds an awful problem.

edit:
I mean save an Glaaery with a set of it's images and save agency with it's gallery at the same form.

thanks for any help

Comment: Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: @pbm Inlines won't work, because it's the ui for the foreign key *from* `Agency` to `Gallery` that @Asima does not like.

Comment: Personally, I think you are trying to do too much in the Django admin. It looks to me like you should write your own view, then you can display all the forms you wish.

Comment: U know,I think it's a bad idea to first add an gallery then add a set of images,then go to agency form and add an agency with that gallery,I wanna have gallery and a set of images in Agency add form,is it a hard scenario?well,how can I write a view?

Comment: off course I think having a 2 step form is a good idea,too. I mean user can add an gallery in first step and in second step add a agency for that,is it possible,of course I've found some references in internet but no one were useful.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment above, you're trying to do too much in the Django admin.

Looking at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939010/editing-related-objects-in-modelform/), you are familar with the tools you need to write your own view. Define model forms for your models. Put them in the same form tag in your template. If the form is valid, save with `commit=False` then fix up the foreign keys.

Here's a skeleton view for adding an `Agency` and a `Gallery` together. You could easily add a formset of images at the same time.

```
def add_agency(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        agency_form = AgencyForm(data=request.POST, prefix="agency")
        gallery_form = GalleryForm(data=request.POST, prefix="gallery")
        if agency_form.is_valid() and gallery_form.is_valid():
            gallery = gallery_form.save()
            agency = agency_form.save(commit=False)
            agency.gallery = gallery
            agency.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
    else:
        # left as an exercise
```

If you want a two step form, I recommend you look at formwizard. It's a [separate app](https://github.com/stephrdev/django-formwizard) for Django <=1.3.X], and [included](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) in Django >=1.4.

Comment: I created my own view for it,but now the problem is that it is not like other admin forms,it doesn't have a change list,it doesn't have a link in home page to add and change ... how can I implement theme?

Comment: You might be able to the `ModelAdmin.add_view()`, `ModelAdmin.change_view()` or `ModelAdmin.get_urls()` hooks to integrate your view into the admin. For more info see the [admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin).

Comment: first of all,thank U for your helps.after googling alot,now I think adding a field for HeadImage and a formset for Image to AgencyModelAdmin and overriding save method to save Gallery,Images and Agency at once should be most rewarding than writing my own view and I won't lose admin facilities.but I don't know yet if it's possible to add another form or formset like extra fields to a model admin or not.is it possible?

Comment: You can override `ModelAdmin.form`, but I don't think it's easy to add 'formset like extra fields', so would recommend using the `add_view` and `change_view` hooks instead. Good luck!