# MultiValueDictKeyError at /physicians/3/update/ "u'form-1-id'"; Saving formsets

Tags: django, formset

im trying to save all the forms from my formset and it doesnt pass the validation. here is my code

```
def UpdatePhysician(request,id):

physician = get_object_or_404(Physician, id=id)
SpecialtyFormset = modelformset_factory(PhysicianSpecialties, fields=('specialty',),max_num=1, labels=None, )
formset = SpecialtyFormset(queryset=PhysicianSpecialties.objects.filter(employee_academic_degree__employee__pk=physician.employee.id))



if request.method == "POST":
    formset = SpecialtyFormset(request.POST,)
    for form in formset:
        print(form)

    if (formset.is_valid()):

        for form in formset:
            form.save()



        return HttpResponse('yesh')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('nope')

return render(request, 'UpdatePhysician.html', {
                                                'formset': formset,
                                                })
```

it throws me an error like this

"MultiValueDictKeyError at /physicians/3/update/
"u'form-1-id'""

**EDIT**

I noticed when i have just 1 object in the formset it saves the record perfectly

**My template is**

```
{% extends 'prescription_menu.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
 {% block css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL   }}site/css/select2.css"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Physicians{% endblock title %}

{% block container %}
    {% csrf_token %}
<form  method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}
                {% crispy form %}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-id-save">
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
 {% endblock container %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939010/editing-related-objects-in-modelform/8143709#8143709).

Comment: If that doesn't help, please show your template.

Comment: Thanks for the help but im having the same problem, my template is the following

Comment: Why do you want a formset if you have `max_num=1`? Wouldn't a simple model form be easier in that case?

Comment: ok, my logic is the following:
use the formsets to show all the specialties of the physicians
modify them
and save them all in once.

if the physicisian have 2 specialties for example:
General Medicine and Cardiology form a list of 40 specialties
the template shows 2 forms (from the formset) with a dropdown list each with General Medicine and Cardiology selected respectively.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that when i saved just 1 record it pass the validation, so it wasnt the formset, was something in post, so I realized that when each form renders the first one follow the layout from the form crispy layout, but the next one renders wrapped on form tags, so i made a special layout class at the bottom of my view to gives layout to my formset and is the following

```
class SpecialtyFormsetHelper(FormHelper):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SpecialtyFormsetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.form_tag = False
    self.render_required_fields = True
```

and the final code is the following:

```
def UpdatePhysician(request,id):

physician = get_object_or_404(Physician, id=id)
SpecialtyFormset = modelformset_factory(PhysicianSpecialties, fields=('specialty',),max_num=1,)
formset = SpecialtyFormset(queryset=PhysicianSpecialties.objects.filter(employee_academic_degree__employee__pk=physician.employee.id))
helper = SpecialtyFormsetHelper()
if request.method == "POST":

    formset = SpecialtyFormset(request.POST,)
    for form in formset:
        print(form)

    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
            form.save()

        return HttpResponse('yesh')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('nope')

return render(request, 'UpdatePhysician.html', {
                                                'formset': formset,
                                                'helper': helper,
                                                })
```

and i just add helper to the template render

like this:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            {% crispy form helper %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Thank You  Alasdair for your help :), you were very helpful