# Django initialise data in forms.inlineformset_factory

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to use an inlineformset and there are certain fields which will be the same for this particular user in this instance.   I want to initialise/default these fields but cannot work out how to do it.

**MODELS**
Basically, my models look something like ...

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = 'Organisation Name',
        max_length = 30
    )
    slug = models.SlugField (
        verbose_name = "Slug",
        allow_unicode = True,
        unique=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User
    )

class Factor (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name = 'Factor',
        max_length = 30
    )


class SupportingDocument(models.Model):
    f = models.FileField(
        upload_to ='supporting_document/'
    )
    factor = models.ForeignKey(
        Factor,
        blank = True,
        null = True
        )
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation)
```

**FORMS**

```
class OrganisationFactorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Organisation
        fields = ['user']
        widgets = {
            'user' : forms.HiddenInput(),
        }

class SupportingDocumentInline(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SupportingDocument
        exclude = ['id', ]
        widgets = {
            'factor' : forms.HiddenInput(),
            'organisation' : forms.HiddenInput(),
            'f' : forms.FileInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'})
        }

SupportingDocumentInlineFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Organisation,
    SupportingDocument,
    form=SupportingDocumentInline,
    extra=1,
    exclude = ['id'],
    can_delete=True,
    can_order=True)
```

**VIEWS**  I want to default the factor record so that when I display the form I can do something like

```
    if self.request.POST:
        form_count = int(self.request.POST['supportingdocument_set-TOTAL_FORMS'])
        ctx['supporting_documents'] = SupportingDocumentInlineFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.get_object())

        for x in range(form_count):
            mutable = self.request.POST._mutable
            self.request.POST._mutable = True
            self.request.POST['supportingdocument_set-' + str(x) +'-factor'] = self.get_factor().id
            self.request.POST._mutable = mutable

    else : ctx['supporting_documents'] = SupportingDocumentInlineFormSet(instance=self.get_object(), queryset=SupportingDocument.objects.filter(factor=self.get_factor(), organisation=self.get_object()))
```

You'll note I am currently overwriting the POST data within the view using `self.request.POST._mutable = True` which works the first time I load a file for an Organisation/Factor combination and thereafter errors with

> MultiValueDictKeyError at ... 
>   "u'supportingdocument_set-0-id'"

I could really use some help here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted!.  I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939010/editing-related-objects-in-modelformset/8143709#8143709).  Bascially, I wasn't declaring the form id in the template when reloading the page.